# Laravel 5.4 : Variables become NULL when sent via E-mail

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, email

i have a website that encrypts, and decrypts data that is entered to a text-box, when i click on "encrypt" the application will send an Email containing the encrypted message.

the problem : the email contains everything, EXCEPT the actual encrypted message.

i'm using [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io) to view the sent emails.
here's the code :

the controller:

```
public function encrypt(Request $request){
    $output = encrypt($request->name);
    Mail::to('kevin@example.com')->send(new EncryptionSent($output));

    return view('decrypt', ['output' => $output,]);
}
```

The Mailables :

```
class EncryptionSent extends Mailable{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $output;

public function __construct($output){
    //
}
public function build(){
    return $this->from('example@example.com')->view('decrypt', ['output' => $this->output]);
}
```

}

The View :

```
@extends ('home')
@section('content')
<div  style = "width: 250px;border: 1px solid #000000;word-wrap:break-word">
<!-- The Decrypted code is located here -->
{{ $output }}
</div>

<form action="{{ url('/decrypt/'.$output)}}" method="POST" class="form-    horizontal">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus"></i> Decrypt!
    </button>
</form>

@endsection
```

i used dd() to find out the problem, but $output always returns the encrypted message in the controller and mailables.

thanks for reading, hoping that someone can help!

Comment: Don't use **global**. Use $output as parameter or as property of object (**$this->output**)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i changed the code; and the results are still the same.

Comment: Hey :) You forgot to set property in the __construct method:
`$this->output = $output`

Comment: @AlexSlipknot thanks for the solution! can you post your answer as a post; instead of a comment? so that i can approve it! :)

Comment: ok, sure, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use **global**. Use $output as parameter or as property of object (**$this->output**) 
And in the __construct method add **$this->output = $output**